# Symfony 4 : doctrine, relationships and twig

Tags: doctrine, twig, one-to-many, symfony4

I'm currently working on my first symfony 4 project and I'm having a problem with my twig templating.
First of all here is a UML diagram of my created objects.

[image: UML]

And my layout should look sorta like this :

[image: Layout]

Here are my entities :

Region

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\RegionRepository")
 */
class Region
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $designation;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Country", mappedBy="region", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $countries;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $initials;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->countries = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDesignation(): ?string
    {
        return $this->designation;
    }

    public function setDesignation(string $designation): self
    {
        $this->designation = $designation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Country[]
     */
    public function getCountries(): Collection
    {
        return $this->countries;
    }

    public function addCountry(Country $country): self
    {
        if (!$this->countries->contains($country)) {
            $this->countries[] = $country;
            $country->setRegion($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCountry(Country $country): self
    {
        if ($this->countries->contains($country)) {
            $this->countries->removeElement($country);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($country->getRegion() === $this) {
                $country->setRegion(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInitials(): ?string
    {
        return $this->initials;
    }

    public function setInitials(string $initials): self
    {
        $this->initials = $initials;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getInitials();
    }


}
```

Continent

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ContinentRepository")
 */
class Continent
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Country", mappedBy="continent", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $countries;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->countries = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode(string $code): self
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Country[]
     */
    public function getCountries(): Collection
    {
        return $this->countries;
    }

    public function addCountry(Country $country): self
    {
        if (!$this->countries->contains($country)) {
            $this->countries[] = $country;
            $country->setContinent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCountry(Country $country): self
    {
        if ($this->countries->contains($country)) {
            $this->countries->removeElement($country);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($country->getContinent() === $this) {
                $country->setContinent(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

Country

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CountryRepository")
 */
class Country
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $iso;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Region", inversedBy="countries")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $region;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Document", mappedBy="country", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $documents;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Continent", inversedBy="countries")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="continent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $continent;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->documents = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIso(): ?string
    {
        return $this->iso;
    }

    public function setIso(string $iso): self
    {
        $this->iso = $iso;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRegion(): ?Region
    {
        return $this->region;
    }

    public function setRegion(?Region $region): self
    {
        $this->region = $region;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Document[]
     */
    public function getDocuments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->documents;
    }

    public function addDocument(Document $document): self
    {
        if (!$this->documents->contains($document)) {
            $this->documents[] = $document;
            $document->setCountry($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeDocument(Document $document): self
    {
        if ($this->documents->contains($document)) {
            $this->documents->removeElement($document);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($document->getCountry() === $this) {
                $document->setCountry(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContinent(): ?Continent
    {
        return $this->continent;
    }

    public function setContinent(?Continent $continent): self
    {
        $this->continent = $continent;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Document

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DocumentRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable()
 */
class Document
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Country", inversedBy="documents")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $level;

    /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     *
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="country_document", fileNameProperty="documentName", size="documentSize")
     *
     * @var File
     */
    private $documentFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $documentName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    private $documentSize;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCountry(): ?Country
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(?Country $country): self
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLevel(): ?int
    {
        return $this->level;
    }

    public function setLevel(int $level): self
    {
        $this->level = $level;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setDocumentFile(?File $document = null): void
    {
        $this->documentFile = $document;

        if (null !== $document) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }
    }

    public function getDocumentFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->documentFile;
    }

    public function setDocumentName(?string $documentName): void
    {
        $this->documentName = $documentName;
    }

    public function getDocumentName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->documentName;
    }

    public function setDocumentSize(?int $documentSize): void
    {
        $this->documentSize = $documentSize;
    }

    public function getDocumentSize(): ?int
    {
        return $this->documentSize;
    }

}
```

I have 4 regions. These regions each have multiple countries who are affiliated to a continent and have 2 documents attributed to them.
How should I proceed to get the layout I want ?

Comment: Too broad, we don't know how your entities are connected codewise

Comment: Yeah I realized that this morning. Entities code added !